# check to check DB tables exists in Django?

Tags: django, database, django-queryset

I write this form for the product, that's got all brand and then set choice list for brand input

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    BRAND_CHOICE = Brand.objects.all()
    model = Product
    fields = '__all__'
    widgets = {
        'brand': forms.Select(choices=BRAND_CHOICE),
     }
```

but I take error when run

> python manage.py migrate

an error that I taken

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: app_product_brand
```

So how can I check DB and if tables exist then make a query to Database?

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py makemigrations` before running migrate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check in your models.py  app_product_brand , if you have this model , if you are already having do

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate app_product_brand
```

If not you can check all tables using this

```
from django.db import connection
all_tables = connection.introspection.table_names()
```